# Apache / Define stickiness with JSESSIONID

Tags: apache, apache-modules

I try to define stickiness in Apache. Here is the definition in proxy.conf:

```
<Proxy balancer://fs1>
    BalancerMember https://localhost:5006/doc route=node1
    BalancerMember https://localhost:5008/doc route=node2
    ProxySet stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /doc balancer://fs1
```

or:

```
ProxyPass "/doc " "balancer://fs1" stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid scolonpathdelim=On
<Proxy balancer://fs1>
    BalancerMember https://localhost:5006/doc route=node1
    BalancerMember https://localhost:5008/doc route=node2
</Proxy>
```

I try to use the url query param in order to achieve stickiness (because I understand that is not recommended to override cookie). As written in the Apache documentation:

> The second way of implementing stickyness is URL encoding. The web
>   server searches for a query parameter in the URL of the request. The
>   name of the parameter is specified again using stickysession. The
>   value of the parameter is used to lookup a member worker with route
>   equal to that value. Since it is not easy to extract and manipulate
>   all URL links contained in responses, generally the work of adding the
>   parameters to each link is done by the back-end generating the
>   content. In some cases it might be feasible doing this via the web
>   server using mod_substitute or mod_sed. This can have negative impact
>   on performance though.

I send the following request 10 times in postman:

```
https://{{myserver}}/doc?jsessionid=node1
```

I notice that the requests are passed to `node1` (5 requests) and to `node2` (also 5 requests). But I define the stickysession so it should choose `node1`, and go to this node every time.

My goal is that the client will send the request `https://{{myserver}}/doc?jsessionid=nodeX`, and the request will pass to `nodeX` (**without using cookie..**, only using stickyness is URL encoding).

For example, the client sends the request `https://{{myserver}}/doc?jsessionid=node1` 10 times. Every 10 times the request will be served by `https://localhost:5006`.

What I do wrong?

Comment: You said you defined a "header" "jsessionid  a12". But the Apache configuration will look for a _cookie_ by the name of JSESSIONID with values node1 or node2. What is the input, a cookie or not?

Comment: @covener: Thanks for your comment. I try now to use the URL query param. So I send the following {myserver}/doc?jsessionid=node1. It still go to 5006 & 5008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some searching, I have identified the problem. In order to route via URL request parameters you must include a '.' before the 'node1' like so:

```
https://{{myserver}}/doc?jsessionid=.node1
```

This blog post pointed me in the right direction:

> It is very important that the routes are named by an alphanumeric
>   prefix, a dot and then a number. Eg: server.1, t.2 etc. The
>   mod_proxy_balancer code splits this route name using the dot and uses
>   the second value as the route number. So s.1 would point to “route=1"
>   http://hkrishnan.in/2013/10/14/debugging-apache-mod_proxy_balancer/

I have tested this myself and it works great!